# Persons with high sentiment impact factor

Tags: stock-market

I'm planning an empirical study on the impact of social media on the stock market.
Therefore I would like to pick out several people who could have a big impact with their posts on social media. However, I am unsure which people I should include in the analysis.
Elon Musk or Cathie Wood could be two examples.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?
Or does anyone know a list of people who might be eligible?

Comment: Welcome to Economics:SE. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, [we expect questions to provide evidence of prior research](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help), and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Answer (score 3):

I think asking people for a list here may lead to sample bias or a small sample set.

If you want a more replicable approach, you could simply take the top influencers based on followers or retweets on social media platforms like Twitter, Stocktwits, etc.